# tinymce storing generated markup in database security concerns

Tags: javascript, security, tinymce

I have used tinymce as a part of a forum feature on my site. I am taking the innerHTML of the textarea and storing it inside a SQL database.

I retrieve the markup when viewing thread posts.

Is there any security concerns doing what I am doing? Does tinymce have any inbuilt features to stop malicious content / markup being added and therefore saved?

Comment: Let me know if there's anything I can add to my answer to help you.

Answer (score 2):

TinyMce does a pretty good job ant content scrubbing and input cleanup (on the client side).  Being a very popular web rich text editor, the creators have spent a lot of work on making it fairly secure in terms of preventing simple copy and paste of malicious content in to the editor.  You can do things like enable/disable cleanup, specify what tags/attributes/characters are allowed, etc.

See the [TinyMce Configurations Page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration).  Options of note include:  `valid_elements`, `invalid_elements`, `verify_html`, `valid_styles`, `invalid_styles`, and `extended_valid_elements`

Also:  instead of grabbing the innerHtml of the textarea, you should probably use tinyMce's getContent() function.  see:  [getContent()](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent)

**BUT this is all client-side javascript!**

Although these featuers are nice, all of this cleanup still happens on the client.  So conceivably, the client JS could be modified to stop escaping/removing malicious content.  Or someone could POST bad data to your request handlers without ever going thru the browser (using curl, or any other number of tools).

So tinyMce provides a nice baseline of client scrubbing, however to be secure, the server should assume that anything it is being sent is dirty and should thus treat all content with caution.

**Things that can be done by the server:**

Even if you implement the most sophisticated client-side validation/scrubbing/prevention, that is worthless as far as your backend's security is concerned.  An excellent reference for preventing malicious data injections can be found on the [OWASP Cross Site Scripting Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and the [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  Not only do you have to protect against SQL injection type attacks, but also XSS attacks if any user submitted data will be displayed on the website for other unsuspecting users to view.

In addition to sanitizing user input data on the server, you can also try things such as [mod_security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ModSecurity) to squash requests that contain certain patterns that are indicative of malicious requests.  You can also enforce max length of inputs on both the client and server side, as well as adding a max request size for your server to make sure someone doesn't try and send a GB of data.  How to set a max request size will vary from server to server.  Violations of max request size should result in a [HTTP 413/Request Entity Too Large](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E413.html)

Comment: unfortunately getContent is out of the question because I am accessing the markup from within an ASPX backend - and I dont know how from the server side I can invoke a client side javascript to hit me back the content!

Answer (score 0):

Further to [@jCuga's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663119/413180), you should implement a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) on any pages where you output the rich text.

This allows you to effectively stop inline script from being executed by the browser. It is currently [supported by](http://caniuse.com/contentsecuritypolicy) modern browsers such as Chrome and Firefox.

This is done by a HTTP response header from your page.

e.g.

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

will stop inline JavaScript from being executed if a user managed to inject it into your page (it will be ignored with a warning), but will allow script tags referencing either your own server or `https://apis.google.com`. This can be customised to your needs as required.

Even if you use a HTML sanitizer to strip any malicious tags, it is a good idea to use this in combination with a CSP just in case anything slips through the net.